# How can I check if a Prolog rules was already fired?

Tags: prolog, artificial-intelligence

I need to check if a rule was already "fired" before to fire it again. I mean before asserting a new fact I need to know if the same fact was already asserted in the previous loop iteration.

I tried to use a list but I think they aren't so "friendly" for my problem. What else can I use to do this?

Comment: Upon successful application of a rule you can record it using `assert` and check whether the rule has been asserted before. This is under assumption that you need to apply every rule only once (as opposed to e.g. applying it only once for every possible input). Some more refined bookkeeping is needed but I cannot show it in the comment.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is on hold, it's perfectly clear to me. You could write a meta-interpreter which checks, but this is unlikely to be within reach if you're a newbie. Still, it's the approach I would be inclined to try. [This link](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/prolog_misc/acomip.html) has a discussion of some simple meta-interpreters, including one that can detect redundant rules. Give it a shot, it may be exactly what you need.

Comment: One question: you don't mean "before asserting a new fact", you mean "before entering a clause," right?

Comment: @TonyH: you could try `..., (fact -> true ; assert(fact)), ...`, as Alexander already suggested. Of course, be aware those assertions are **not** undone if your program (as usual in Prolog) need to backtrack. This fact could make you to reconsider 'friendness' of lists...

Comment: Thank you all for the response. I'm sorry for the misunderstood.. I'm trying to specify better what I need:
I insert into the system the fact, at the end of the input data the fact are processed to get a solution, and this works fine. 
But I need to check if exists another solution (different OR partially different from the first one). To do so I need to know which rules are already fired (in previous loop) to fire a different rule (if exists).
How can I do this?

Comment: @TonyH - you might consider the failure-driven loop that would fail after generating a solution and force Prolog to backtrack and explore other possibilities: `failure_driven_loop(Info):- generate( Info,Term), fail. failure_driven_loop(Info).` (example is from Paul Brna's book: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node95.html). Solutions found can be recorded with `assert`. As CapelliC has pointed out, assertions are not undone if your program backtracks, so your solutions will be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rephrasing my comment above as an answer to elaborate a bit more on it.

You might consider the failure-driven loop that would fail after generating a solution and force Prolog to backtrack and explore other possibilities:

```
failure_driven_loop(Info):- generate(Info,Term), fail. 
failure_driven_loop(Info).
```

(example is from [Paul Brna's book](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/pbrna/prologbook/node95.html)). In this example `Term` records a solution and `generate/2` generates solutions for the given `Info`. The second clause is needed to make the loop succeed when all solutions have been exhausted.

Once a solution has been generated, the first clause fails and the execution backtracks, i.e., Prolog will try to find a different proof for `generate(Info,Term)`, which will commonly involve different clauses either for `generate/2` itself or for one of the predicates directly or indirectly invoked by `generate/2`. If you would like to ensure that once `generate/2` has used one of its clauses it should not try and reuse the same clause, you should add cuts, i.e., instead of

```
generate(Info,Term) :- solve_somehow(Info,Term).
generate(Info,Term) :- solve_in_some_other_way(Info,Term).
```

you should write

```
generate(Info,Term) :- solve_somehow(Info,Term), !.
generate(Info,Term) :- solve_in_some_other_way(Info,Term), !.
```

Solutions found by `generate/2` can be recorded with `assert`. As @CapelliC has pointed out, assertions are not undone if your program backtracks, so the failure driven loop preserves your solutions:

```
:- dynamic solution/1.

failure_driven_loop(Info):- generate(Info,Term), assert(solution(Term)), fail. 
failure_driven_loop(Info).
```